# Creating a drop down list to zoom into selected country for Leaflet maps

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

Using leaflet control, I would like to create a drop down menu which lists country names. When selecting a country on this list, the map will zoom into the selected country on that map.

```
countriesLayer = L.geoJson(countries,
            {
                onEachFeature: countriesOnEachFeature
            }
        ).addTo(map);
```

This layer loads my countries onto the map from my geojson file.

```
var geoJsonFeatures = [];
function countriesOnEachFeature(feature, layer){
        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.Country){
            geoJsonFeatures.push(feature);
        }
}
```

And then I have a loaded array which holds my geojson data as objects in the array.

```
 var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});  
 legend.onAdd = function (map) {  
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');  
    var dropDownContent ='<select>';  
    for (var i = 0; i < uniqueCountryArray.length; i++ ){  
        dropDownContent += '<option value=' + "'" + uniqueCountryArray[i]["ISO3"] + "'>" + uniqueCountryArray[i]["Country"] + '</option>';  
       }  
        dropDownContent += '</select>';  
        div.innerHTML = dropDownContent;  
        div.firstChild.onmousedown = div.firstChild.ondblclick = L.DomEvent.stopPropagation;  
        return div;  
};
```

Next, I created the drop down list with it's ISO 3 code value attached to it.

```
$('select').change(function(){
            var selectedCountry = document.getElementById('ddVal').value;
            for (i=0 ; i < geoJsonFeatures.length; i++){
                if(selectedCountry == geoJsonFeatures[i].properties.ISO_3_CODE){
                    map.fitBounds(geoJsonFeatures[i].getBounds(),{padding: [10, 10]});
                }else if(selectedCountry == 'Anything'){
                    map.fitWorld();
                }
            }
});
```

I get the ISO 3 code value from the select, compare it to the geoJson ISO 3 code in the array. When it matches, I want to use the object in the geoJson array to center it to the country selected on my Leaflet map. Hopefully I can get the message across. This is probably not the best way in doing it. Looking for ways to get it done, or perhaps getting this way to work. I am not too experienced so I would greatly appreciate some easy to understand examples. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this one are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to put all of your code into a wrapper div that you have as `position:relative;` while making the children, including your `<select>`, `position: absolute;`. In other words, build the `<select>` separate.

Comment: I have made edits to my question which provides more context. Please have a look!

Comment: For more information, I cant use getBounds() on my geoJson array objects.